# Updating excel based on multiple arrays

Tags: office365, power-automate, excel-365

I am attempting to create a Power Automate flow to send email, once the email is sent it will update the Worksheet with DateSent (complete), it will not send if DateSent is already populated (complete) and finally, if EmailAddress is blank it will record the PIN (customer ID) on a separate sheet "EmailErrors" for a manual flow later - if the PIN already exists on that other sheet it should only update the DateUpdated column (or ignore), not create a new duplicate line. I am experiencing issues with the latter where my flow is auto adding an "apply to each" as I'm trying to see if value already exists in EmailErrors sheet, this causes a loop where multiple duplicate lines are created. I feel I am missing something simple to achieve this but I am a loss, help appreciated!

[image]